# Installing Linux on a single primary partition

Tags: linux, partition, dual-boot

Is it possible to install Linux on a single primary partition? I already have three primary partitions occupied by Windows 7 which I cannot give up.

Comment: Yes, and IMO (contra the conventional wisdom) using more than one partition on a stand-alone desktop has next to no value beyond setting yourself up for inefficient use of space.

Comment: @goldilocks not even `swap` and `/home`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is. There is no *requirement* for separate partitions in a Linux install, it's just a very good idea. Having certain partitions separate protects you from losing everything if a single partition fails. It is also good to have your `$HOME` on a separate partition as that facilitates reinstalling or changing distributions.

However, you are free to set up Linux on a single partition and should have absolutely no problems with it.

A better option, however, is to create a fourth partition as an [Extended Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition). That allows you to create multiple logical partitions within it and so have a Linux system with separate partitions for certain folders.

Comment: Great! This is all I wanted to know

Answer (score 0):

Using a LiveCD Linux such as [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) you can open `gparted` ([Gnome Partition Editor](http://gparted.org/)) to organize your hard disk.
You can then resize your primary partitions and create a new extended partition on the remaining free space. Then create at least two logical partition inside the extended one :
1. An *ext4* partition for the system root filesystem `/`
2. A *swap* partition with the 2*RAM as size.

Then you can start installing your Linux.

Comment: @terdon, Merci bien !